# what is the purpose of installed facet="jst.web" in org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, servlets, eclipse-plugin

Whenever I import a maven project to Eclipse I get version 2.3 for facet jst.web. I have to manually change in this file (changing via right click on project > projects > choose 3.1 for Dynamic Web Module doesn't allow me to click in Apply).

Although it seems to be a small issue, I have to do it several times otherwise, I do "mvn clean compile" properly but when I right-click in server and try add application I can see it miss spring-web-x.x.x.jar and obviously the application is deployed but it doesn't work at all.

org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.3"/> <!-- I always have to change here to reflect javax.servlet-api version from my pom -->
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.7"/>
</faceted-project>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycomp.springmvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>my-app</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <springsecurityoauth2.version>2.0.10.RELEASE</springsecurityoauth2.version>
        <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security OAuth2-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurityoauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>           
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>my-app</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        <finalName>my-app</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Dynamic Web Module tries to update every time based on settings in Eclipse preference version settings. The Dynamic Web Module provides the provision to use servlet version as one of Web Components in Java EE

Please find more info:
http://www.admfactory.com/how-to-fix-cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-1-error-in-eclipse/

You can also find the servlet/jsp component version in `web.xml`

Example of web.xml DocType in xml DTD version

```
DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_3.dtd
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the relevant steps here, in addition to the link.  What if the link is not available in the future?